# Django desplegado en Heroku. Interfaz administrativa no se ve bien

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

Lo que dice el título. Cuando entro en /admin (zona administrativa) se ve de pena. No hay nada igual que en modo local.

¿ Como se hace para que la zona administrativa se vea como en local ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes subir una imagen por favor para entender mejor cuál es el problema.

Tengo la impresión que que tienes problemas con los archivos estáticos, revisa la configuracion de STATIC, ejecuta `./manage.py collectstatic` y comitea a Heroku.